# Elasticsearch: Updating a field that has been set as a document _id via mapping with a path

Tags: elasticsearch

So basically I have an index that I created, and have set the mapping so that whenever a document is created, the _id of the document is set as one of the fields of the document.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html

This was easy enough, but I noticed that when I update that field (through the Java API), the _id of the document remains the same so the field and _id are out of sync.

Is this intended behaviour? If so, does anyone know why, and if it is a bad idea to set the _id as a field that may frequently change?

If I wanted the _id and the field to be in sync, is reindexing an option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _id is extracted and copied from that field while indexing. 
Also _id is used as routing key and it decides where the document should go in the whole cluster.
Hence its not possible to keep _id as reference to some field , rather that valued is copied to _id before indexing.

If you want to change _id  , re-indexing is the only option.